# How to run npm start without opening browser for react development on linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, linux, npm

I am learning react and find  myself running `npm start` on the terminal a couple of times but its annoying how it opens a new browser window everytime. I'm trying to stop this from happening on linux.

I found a [solution for how to do this on Windows](https://siderite.dev/blog/running-npm-start-without-opening-browser/), but how can I do it on Linux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `BROWSER=none` to the `.env` file should get it solved.

Answer (score 1):

fixed

create a `.env` file next to your `package.json` and put `BROWSER=none` inside

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If the folder /etc/profile.d doesn't exist create it. Then run `touch /etc/profile.d/[any descriptive name here].sh` and open it in the text editor of your choice. Then add `export BROWSER=none` there.
Then logout and login again. If it didn't work then try putting `export BROWSER="none" in the file`.
This is setting an environment variable.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to run `npm start` so often. I've created my project via `create-react-app` which comes with Hot Module Reloading or HMR(restarts the server on any saved edit) in-built.

Starting a new React server multiple times can also be problematic as every time it will run on a different port. If you're integrating an API that has CORS set up for a particular port, it won't work on other instances.

What to do?

1. Create your application using `create-react-app`(cra) or add HMR using some library if you don't want to use `cra`. Here is a [tutorial](https://www.developerhandbook.com/webpack/how-to-add-hot-module-reloading-to-a-react-app/) for that (haven't tested it).
2. Always keep a single dev server running. It will automatically reload on code change.
3. Stop the server by `Ctrl + C` when you don't want to use it.